# Html Table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I have two tables with different table-id in html, that are as follows -

1. table-header - consists of dynamic week wise days + resources
2. table-data in  with same nnumbers of columns...

   for Img - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwvoq.png

The Assign Task is a Button in every cell of table-data , What I need is , whent I click any button, the Pop-up window(Kendowindow which is I m using right now in Javascript preferably) should display respective Cell row's 1st cell i.e resource's name and Id and cell column's 1st cell i.e. Date string.

Please suggest the solutions.... Help is kindly appreciated.

P.S. -- Please don't suggest Kendo Grid or Scheduler, because I can't able produce this kind of format, If you can do  pls share your code and procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with jQuery: **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2355m/4/)**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.assign').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $idx = $(this).parent().index(); // get the index
        var $th = $('table th'); // table heading
        var $date = $th.eq($idx).text();  // get the date by the index
        var $resource = $(this).parents('tr').find("td:first-child").text(); // find the first td in the tr for the resource name.

        // append the date and resource to a paragraph tag.
        $('.result').text("Date : " + $date + " : " + $resource);
   });
 });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date 1</th>
        <th>Date 2</th>
        <th>Date 3</th>
        <th>Date 4</th>
        <th>Date 5</th>
        <th>Date 6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 1</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 2</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 3</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="assign">Assign Task</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>


<p class="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, Appreciate your help...it is explendid, but my problem over here is the header and the data tables are seperate tables with differentId and Class.... so How can I declare them as single class = ?

Comment: @DeeLaw Can you post your HTML, it should be fairly easy to change the code - because you can just reference an index in another table.